# Are user surveys considered "human experiments" by the U.S. National Science Foundation?

Tags: funding, experiment-design

I'm applying for a grant to the National Science Foundation of the United States of America.

The grant is to fund our research in numerical methods for fashion. I want to conduct a survey where I show two images to a human subject. One of the images shows the original dress and the other one shows our simulation. Then, I ask them to grade 1-5 how good they think is the simulation.

I think this is quite harmless stuff for humans (beyond the trauma of our bad taste in fashion), so is this considered experimentation with human subjects for the National Science Foundation of United States of America?

Comment: That sounds like it's in the "exempt" category. But you can't make the decision whether it's exempt yourself -- you still have to submit your study design to your IRB.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth IRB is for experiments, not grants.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist But the question is about the survey to be done for the grant.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It's typical for IRB approval to be part of the grant process. For NIH this is done via the just-in-time mechanism; I'm less familiar with NSF since it's been awhile since I looked at their process, but I'd expect that some statement about human subjects protections is part of the grant itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In almost all circumstances you need IRB approval to carry out the "experiments" that you are contemplating. The reason isn't that taking surveys is, somehow, dangerous, but, rather, that the data you collect might be sensitive. Moreover the subjects of the survey might have privacy concerns and expectations.

So the issue is about the data collected. How will it be maintained? How will it be disseminated? Is it (even potentially) name linked? Etc. The treatment of the data implies some treatment of the subjects.

While there are a few exemptions to IRB approval, the best place to learn if your study falls under exemption is from the IRB itself. It is better to ask and be told that approval isn't needed than to make assumptions.

For your specific situation, the fact that you may be using human models as part of the materials introduces another aspect. An IRB will want to be assured that you have proper releases from everyone.

So, ask.

Since you are concerned about a grant writing process, rather than the experiment itself, it would be wise to run a version of your proposed experiment, not just the questionnaire, past your IRB so that you can assure the NSF that you have your processes in place.

---

The [NSF policy](https://www.nsf.gov/bfa/dias/policy/human.jsp)

Comment: While your point is definitely the more salient one, some surveys would require more than minimal inspection. For example, someone coming in to the human design department wouldn't expect to be asked about their sexual traumas. It would strike me as unethical to drop that on someone without their previous knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your grant application requires you to indicate if you are doing human subjects research.  Yes, you are.  You are experimenting on humans as part of your research.  The level of risk is irrelevant.